# What is the specific name of this distribution?

Tags: distributions, logistic-distribution

I just can’t seem to find the name of this distribution:

$$\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x}) ^2}.$$

From my understanding, it is generally applied to pandemics/epidemics.

None of the statistics books that I have looked at contained any information on it. I would really appreciate if someone can guide me about it.

Comment: This is a *density,* not a distribution.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution.  Writing it as $p(1-p)$ with $p=1/(1+e^{-x})$ is very suggestive ;-).

Comment: @whuher I would have taken the derivative of the logistic function as the cumulative distribution function to come up with this density. How would p(1-p) have any importance here beyond a "numerical accident". I don't see the connection

Comment: @Ggjj11 The connections are many and deep.  You might, for instance, recognize $p(1-p)$ as the variance of a Bernoulli$(p)$ variable as well as the Beta$(2,2)$ density. Moreover, the differential relationship $(1/p)^\prime=p(1-p)$ leads to many nice algebraic formulas for quantities associated with the logistic distribution.  These all can be interpreted in terms of quantities meaningful in epidemics as well as more generally.

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x}) ^2} = \dfrac{e^{x}}{(1+e^{x}) ^2}$ demonstrating the symmetry about $0$ of the standard logistic distribution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the PDF of a [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) with its location parameter set to zero and scale parameter set to one.

In general, a logistic distribution has a PDF as follows, where $\mu$ is the mean and $s$ is the scale (related to, but not the same as, standard deviation and variance).

$$
f_X(x) = \dfrac{
\exp\left(
-\left(x - \mu\right)/s
\right)
}{
s\left(
1 + \exp\left(
-\left(x - \mu\right)/s
\right)
\right)^2
}
$$

If you set $\mu = 0$ and $s = 1$, you get the expression given in the OP.

The CDF is as follows.

$$
F_X(x) = \dfrac{
1
}{
1 + \exp\left(
-\left(x - \mu\right)/s\right)
}
$$

(Note that there is a technical difference between a PDF and a distribution, even if people often use the terms as synonyms in statistical slang. If you look at the edit history, I did it, too.)

Comment: Tldr: start with the logistic function as cdf, then take the derivative to get the PDF in the form of the question

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.